# How can I compare the date of files with REST query?

Tags: development, .net, onedrive-for-business

I am using SharePoint OneDrive for Business and connected to this storage REST API. 
And I need to get metadata only files created or updated after some concrete time

For example,

I need all files, when `"updated date" > than my example date`.

For example I need to realize something like this

```
htt_p://......sharepoint.com/_api/web/ bla bla bla/Files$select ETag,Name where_ TimeLastModified > 2014-05-07T16:12:28Z
```

or maybe existing another way to select files which created or updated after some date..

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I'm little confused. 
Where I can write my date to this REST url?

```
string url = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('KeyEvents')/items?$select=Title,Id,EndDate,EventDate&$orderby=Title asc&$filter=(EndDate  ge  datetime'" + date.toISOString() + "')"
```

like a

```
date.toISOString("2014-05-07T16:12:28Z")?
```

and `ge  datetime` it means "more than"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using ListData.svc:

```
var listUrl = "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/" + listName + "?$filter=StartTime ge datetime'" + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') + "'&$select=Path,Title,StartTime,Id&$orderby=StartTime&$top=" + numberOfItemstoShow
```

Here is an example using Rest

```
string url = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('KeyEvents')/items?$select=Title,Id,EndDate,EventDate&$orderby=Title asc&$filter=(EndDate  ge  datetime'" + date.toISOString() + "')"
```

[moment()](http://momentjs.com) <- is a js library to manipulate dates.